# How to enable camera feature in a sencha touch application using phonegap?

Tags: ios, cordova, sencha-touch-2

I have developed one application in Sencha Touch 2. I want to design a page in such a way that 
the page has a default image and one button below that. By clicking that  button device camera should open (device mainly iPad and iPhone) and after capturing the image lets see it stored in a folder named as "capture" in your device. Then the captured image should replace that default image.

I want to use PhoneGap compulsorily. I have seen PhoneGap APIs for camera but I don't get it how to use it exactly. I am using Mac and Xcode for development.

Comment: Hi! Have you tried the example from the online tutorial / doc? http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.5.0/phonegap_camera_camera.md.html#Camera (First full example)

Comment: hey  i have tried  that  code. But it's working in a html button. But in my application I am creating buttons using js file using model-view-controller method. It's a sencha touch app. Please suggest how can I implement ?

Thanks

Comment: Could you add the js code you used for creating your button in your post?

Comment: ok sure..thanks now I am able to access camera but unable to replace the default image with image i have taken. when I am clicking "USE" button it's just vanishing and deafault image is remain there ... i am posting my code plz see..

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In my app With sencha touch 2 and Phonegap 1.4
in Controller
on take photo button handler

```
onTakePhotoButton: function(){
       // Retrieve image file location from specified source
        navigator.camera.getPicture(uploadPhoto, function (message) {
            alert('Get picture failed');
        }, {
            quality: 50,
            destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
            sourceType: navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA //or PHOTOLIBRARY
        }
        );
        function uploadPhoto(imageURI) {
            var options = new FileUploadOptions();
            options.fileKey = "file";
            var imagefilename = Number(new Date()) + ".jpg";
            options.fileName = imagefilename;
            options.mimeType = "image/jpeg";
            options.chunkedMode = false;
            var params = new Object();
            params.image = imagefilename;
            options.params = params;
            var ft = new FileTransfer();
            ft.upload(imageURI,your_request_upload_url_on_server, win, fail, options);
        }

        function win(r) {
            console.log("Code = " + r.responseCode);
            console.log("Response = " + r.response);
            console.log("Sent = " + r.bytesSent);
            var json_obj = Ext.decode(r.response);//remote server funciton upload return json type
            if(json_obj!=null && json_obj.response.image_name!=null){
                console.log(json_obj.response.image_name);
                imageDisplay.setSrc(your_image_root_tmp+json_obj.response.image_name+'?dc='+Number(new Date()));
            }else{
                Ext.Msg.alert('Errors', "The server response failure!");
            }            

        }

        function fail(error) {
            alert("An error has occurred: Code = " + error.code);
        }  
}
```

you can refer more detail here http://zacvineyard.com/blog/2011/03/upload-a-file-to-a-remote-server-with-phonegap

Comment: I have tried your code but it's not working. it's showing blank page. I think problem is declaring several functions in the same js page. "navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, { quality: 100 });" function is working fine but "onPhotoDataSuccess" function is not been called. same thing is happening in your code also... suggest  some alternatives..

Thanks....fabre

Comment: try getPicture function with callback uploadPhoto function. uploadPhoto function with callback win function and fail function.

Answer (score 0):

capturePhoto:function(){

```
       navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, { quality: 50 });

       function onPhotoDataSuccess(imageData) {
       // Uncomment to view the base64 encoded image data
       // console.log(imageData);

       // Get image handle
       //
       var smallImage = document.getElementById('userLogo');

       // Unhide image elements
       //
       smallImage.style.display = 'block';

       // Show the captured photo
       // The inline CSS rules are used to resize the image
       //
       smallImage.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
```

plz verify ...